# I want to connect the "send" button of a website that accepts the details of volunteersin such a way that it autofills a Google form

Tags: javascript, html

The problem that I am having is integrating it into the actual website. I already was able to create the code seperately using basic html and js. However, when I am trying to use the code in the website which requires this functionality, I am unable to do so. Here is the code which I made:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Form Demo</title>
    <style>
        #googleForm {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="site-form">
        <h1>Contact Form</h1>
        <form id="contactForm">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" required><br>
            
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" required><br>
            
            <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="tel" id="phone" required><br>
            
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <input type="text" id="message" required><br>
            <!-- Add more fields as needed -->
            
            <button type="button" onclick="autofillGoogleForm()">Autofill Google Form</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <div id="google-form">
        <iframe id="googleForm" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeHiRlGBYyWrDDg2ggYgLy-CM2bvJ1ZG8JchR95U_PjnAYXVA/viewform?usp=sf_link" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function autofillGoogleForm() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
  // Add more fields as needed.

  var googleFormUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeHiRlGBYyWrDDg2ggYgLy-CM2bvJ1ZG8JchR95U_PjnAYXVA/viewform?usp=sf_link";
  googleFormUrl += "&entry.2005620554=" + encodeURIComponent(name);
  googleFormUrl += "&entry.1166974658=" + encodeURIComponent(email);
  googleFormUrl += "&entry.839337160=" + encodeURIComponent(phone);
  googleFormUrl += "&entry.1227607852=" + encodeURIComponent(message);

  // Add more query parameters for additional fields.

  var iframe = document.getElementById("googleForm");
  iframe.src = googleFormUrl;
  document.getElementById("contactForm").style.display = "none";
  iframe.style.display = "block"; // Show the embedded Google Form after autofilling
}
```

The above code is working as expected.

Now, the problem is this:

```
<div class="row block-9">
          <div class="col-md-6 pr-md-5">
            <h4 class="mb-4">Do you have any questions?</h4>
            <form action="#">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Message">     </textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

This is the form which in which I have to integrate this. It is proving quite impossible.

P.S.: I am a complete beginner and everything I did was using different websites and ai.

I tried to make the form the same way as I did my original code, using the classes and then creating and storing the js file and linking the file thereafter. However, it did not work. After that, I tried to essentially copy paste the code I had pre-written. That too did not work. What I noticed is that the Send Message button took me back to the same contact page that it was in, and when I replaced the entire code, I was unable to click the "Autofill Google Form" button.

Comment: What is not working? Please explain yourself better, also please only add the relevant code

Comment: @DarkBee the Send Message button is not working and neither is the information being relayed to the google form, unlike the code I have provided at the start.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### I managed to replicate your code and solved the issue.

> I noticed your inputs have no IDs in them which makes the variables
> `name, email, phone, message` null.

---

### 2nd

The form does not have the `onclick` attribute as well. Also the form didn' have and ID btw.

```html
    <div class="col-md-6 pr-md-5">
        <h4 class="mb-4">Do you have any questions?</h4>
        <form id="contactForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Message">     </textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" onclick="autofillGoogleForm()" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: The Send Message button is redirecting me to the same page and not running the javascript file. I tried to copy-paste your solution, but it did the same thing again. The frustrating part is that I tried this on another template and it works, it works in the simple webpage format, it is only not working in the website I want it to.

Comment: you can disable the form redirecting with `e.preventDefault()` when the form is submitted, if that helps.